# Is there a Mac 68k emulator for Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, mac, emulation

I have a oldie but goodie program for the 68k macintosh series that I would like to run on Ubuntu 12.04. How can that be done? I have used Basilisk on Win XP but that PC now has, well of course, Ubuntu 12.04.

Cheers, Masa

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you need, but I had tested in the past this emulator and it works perfectly (you may need a OS image though, it can run up to Mac 9 if I remember correctly). http://minivmac.sourceforge.net.